# Linux Mint 19.2 Cinnamon 64-bit strange behavior with "info" command

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, man, gnu, info

I have a Linux Mint 19.2 Cinnamon 64-bit install running on ZFS root. I occasionally use the `info` command to look up things which I can't remember off-hand, for example, obscure details of C format strings.

When I issue an `info printf` and then I navigate to "*Note ‘printf’ format directives:" and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> I receive the following error:

> "Cannot find node 'Output Conversion Syntax'"

I know that the above used to work. The last time I had a problem with info was when an `info info` command produced another unknown node error. I fixed this with:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install texinfo texinfo-doc-nonfree
```

Now, though, I cannot fix the problem. I think it may be related to the following bug: [info missing help docs `info info` and `H` command return error](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/texinfo/+bug/1789298)

Can anyone offer any help on how to resolve whatever problem is causing info to malfunction?

Comment: On my Ubuntu system, it was necessary to install the `glibc-doc-reference` package in order to provide this info node. You might want to try that since Mint is Ubuntu-based.

Answer (score 0):

@steeldriver (https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/65304/steeldriver) came up with the solution :

> On my Ubuntu system, it was necessary to install the glibc-doc-reference package > in order to provide this info node. You might want to try that since Mint is
>   Ubuntu-based.

This solved the problem perfectly! :D Thanks! :)

Some update to Linux Mint must have screwed up the texinfo database, but installing glibc-doc-reference solved the problem.

Thanks,

jdb2